# Should I consider this a normal phenomenon, or should I consider it an anomaly?

Tags: classification

I am doing a network architecture search (NAS).

I have two directories, `train_data_npy` and `valid_data_npy` where there are 3013 and 1506 `*.npy` files, respectively.

Each `*.npy` file has 11 columns of float types, of which the first eight columns are features and the last three columns are one-hot-encoded labels (characters) of three classes.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
f1      f2      f3      f4   f5   f6   f7   f8          ---classes---
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.559   9.22    0.0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
5.512   6.891   10.589  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
7.082   8.71    7.227   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.352   9.883   12.492  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.711   10.422  13.44   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
7.12    9.283   12.723  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.408   9.277   12.542  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.608   9.686   12.793  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.723   8.602   12.168  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

Given the format of the data, I have written two scripts.

`cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_with_ohe.py` uses OHE labels as they are, and `cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_without_ohe.py` converts OHE data into integers. I.e., I use eight columns for features and only one column for the labels, and OHE is converted into numbers $1$, $2$, $3$. I want to predict $1$, $2$, $3$.

The first one achieves an accuracy of `0.40`, and the second one achieves an accuracy of `0.97`.

Should I consider this a normal phenomenon, or should I consider it an anomaly?

Two scripts are using the same features and classes and looking for the best architecture to solve a classification problem. One is representing the classes as OHE, and the other is representing the classes as integers. My expectation was that they would produce similar accuracy, as the only practical difference between these specifications was the representation of the labels. However, since the accuracies are different, I am curious what might have caused this issue.

Comment: I mean...evidently it can happen, even if it is an anomaly and an unusual occurrence. Do you mean to ask if it should be suspected as a software bug? $//$ Do you mean that you still use the three columns when you go without OHE, or do you encode the labels in one column as numbers like $1,2,3?$

Comment: That part about the $1,2,3$ is useful and should be included in the original question. $//$ I disagree with the vote to close this as a programming question. How to encode categorical data in a regression is $100\%$ within the scope of statistics and Cross Validated. The question can be addressed without any reference to a programming language and without any code at all.

Comment: There's a simple and direct way to determine if this is a bug: write a unit test for the loss function and then test the two cases (OHE, ints).

Comment: Wait, the $1,2,3$ are the outcomes you want to predict or are additional features to predict some other outcome of interest?

Comment: According to you, the only difference is the loss functions. You can unit test the loss functions.

Comment: If you're getting different accuracies between two different runs of the search procedure, then it's not at all surprising that they're different: you're comparing two different model configurations. So any details that are different between the two models can explain the differences in the accuracies, even if there are no software bugs. You're comparing apples and orangutangs.

Comment: You need an answer to tell you that two different models might have two different accuracies?

Comment: Both questions are about how to use software, which is off-topic.

Comment: If you're asking about how to compute a certain loss function with different encodings, then you'll need to completely rewrite this question to explain (1) what loss function you're using and (2) a reproducible example of the inputs and outputs that you are computing using that loss function. As it stands, all we know is that you have 2 scripts with two different answers. All anyone can do is guess.

Comment: @Sycorax, I am not using any loss functions. This is an Autokeras NAS script. It searches for an appropriate loss function by itself.

Comment: Not an on-topic question because it is about how the NAS software works.

Comment: @Sycorax, No. This is about encoding.

Comment: If the NAS software is just flipping through a list of possible losses regardless of how the data is encoded, then the entire procedure is bogus, and your problem is much more fundamental because it's spinning its wheels on completely nonsensical models. You can represent a category by an integer index, but apparently your software might fit a Poisson or negative binomial to that integer because it's an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the software you use is changing the loss function or evaluation criterion. That is, when you get performance of 0.40 on one model and 0.97 on the other, these numbers do not refer to the same quantity. Perhaps the first number does refer to classification accuracy (which has its own set of issues [[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603663/academic-reference-on-the-drawbacks-of-accuracy-f1-score-sensitivity-and-or-sp)]), but that doesn't mean the second number is accuracy. With the values coded as numbers, I would first suspect the second value to refer to mean squared error, possibly root mean squared error.

I also could believe that, when you have three columns of output, the value being calculated is a multivariate metric, perhaps mean Euclidean distance between 3-D observations and 3-D predictions. However, the key point is that the two numbers you are getting do not seem to refer to the same calculation and should not be compared anymore than you would compare the accuracy score of one model to the sensitivity score of another model. In fact, it might be that, depending on the data, the values being reported as measures of performance are not oriented the same way (such as accuracy and mean squared error) in that one might be best when it is high while the other might be best when it is low.

Comment: One check worth doing for the integer-encoded variant is looking at what is predicted by the model. If the outputs are floats that never equal any of the three integers and span a range like 1 to 3 (perhaps sometimes below 1 and sometimes above 3), then you know the 0.97 doesn't refer to accuracy.